# How do I perform a push segue within a container

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, containers

Hi I am programming an app for ios6 and and am using the new container feature. It all works but when i perform a push segue, it pushes, but does it full screen. I want the 'View after Segue to be in the container also. Can anyone help?

[image].......[image].......[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI here's a general how-to on putting "containers in containers!" http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've found the answer to my own Question! (...Again)

Instead of putting the navigation controller here:

[image]

I put it here:

[image]

Comment: how u handled back button?